# Spinning wheel function does not always exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, tkinter

I have a function that loops a spinning wheel gif to show a running process. When the process finishes the function is called again with a different value (on/off) and the `Label` changes to a ✓. If I only have a couple threads from `threadspawner()` kick off then they finish just fine and change the `label` to a  ✓. if I start alot of threads (like 12) at the same time then the threads finish just fine but the spinning wheel for one or two labels is sometimes not changed to a ✓.

Note that in the example below I couldn't get the loader to stop and change to a ✓. Maybe this is part of where im messing up but in my code it switches just fine.

Should I be representing the load wheel differently or calling the loader('off') differently?

I tried using a global variable for each thread and setting that to True when the thread starts and then off when the thread ends. This only works if I update the variable in the loader loop to get the new value and that means I have to create a different loader function for each thread which is alot of extra code. I tried using a `while` loop instead of `if` but it changed nothing.

I want to use the same loader function for the spinning wheel that runs for each thread. If that is not the best way to do it please point me in the right direction.

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading
main = Tk()


def threadspawner():
    global var1
    global var2
    print(var1)
    if var1.get() == 2:

        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: loader(lbl1, 'on')) #<-- starts the spinning wheel to show that something is happening
        thread1.start()
        time.sleep(1)  #start doing stuff here
        loader(lbl1, 'off') #<-- Turns off the spinning wheel
        thread1.join()
    if var2.get() == 2:
        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: loader(lbl1, 'on')) #<-- starts the spinning wheel to show that something is happening
        thread2.start()
        time.sleep(2)
        loader(lbl2, 'off')#<-- Turns off the spinning wheel
        thread2.join()

var1 = IntVar()
chk1 = Checkbutton(main, text='process1', onvalue=2, offvalue=0, variable=var1)
chk1.grid(row=1)
lbl1 = Label(main, text='')
lbl1.grid(row=1, column=1)

var2 = IntVar()
chk2 = Checkbutton(main, text='process2', variable=var2)
chk2.grid(row=2)
lbl2 = Label(main, text='')
lbl2.grid(row=2, column=1)

strt = Button(main, text='Start', command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=lambda: threadspawner()).start())
strt.grid(columnspan=2)

def loader(label, switch):
    global lbl1
    global lbl2

    #im using images for my program but you do not have them so I use keyboard entries below to represent

    #img = PhotoImage(file='icons\\wheel.gif', format="gif -index 0")
    #img1 = PhotoImage(file='icons\\wheel.gif', format="gif -index 1")
    #img2 = PhotoImage(file='icons\\wheel.gif', format="gif -index 2")
    if switch == 'off':
        label['text'] = '✓'
        return
    if switch == 'on':
        print('starting loop')
        if switch == 'on':
            label['text'] = '/'
        time.sleep(.1)
        if switch == 'on':
            label['text'] = '-'
        time.sleep(.1)
        if switch == 'on':
            label['text'] = '\\'
        time.sleep(.1)
        if switch == 'on':
            loader(label, 'on')
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything here to guarantee that you turn the spinner off *after* you turn it on.

Comment: Is the only reliable way to do that to use a variable 'on' when the thread starts and variable 'off' at the end and then update the variable in the loader loop?

Comment: Why are you turning it off and on from separate threads? And why are you turning the spinner off *before* you wait for the other thread to complete?

Comment: You cannot safely access Tkinter functions from more than one thread.  Using threads for lengthy tasks is a reasonable solution, but you must somehow arrange for any GUI updates on their behalf to be delivered to the main thread (via a Queue, perhaps), and executed there.

Comment: @user2357112 I want to represent the running thread next to the Checkbutton that is used to launch that thread. Having a spinning wheel there was the best way I found. For simplicity I tried controlling the spinning wheel for each thread with the loader function. How would you recommend I show that a thread is running/finished to a user in the GUI?

Comment: @jasonharper So the call to start the spinning wheel and the call to stop it need to be processed through a queue? Are you saying that the way im doing it, multiple threads are trying to access the loader function at the same time and this causes problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with what you were doing is that `switch` is a local variable, so when the `loader` function is started, the spinner is started, but when it is stopped, the `switch` parameter being passed to the endless chain of loader functions is still `'on'`, so even though the label is set to the `'✓'`, the text is immediately reset to continue the loading animation; When the loader function is called with parameter `'off'`, the `switch` variable only has the value `'off'` in the local scope of that function call.

A quick and dirty fix is to create a new global variable, which can be used to stop the loader functions calling itself forever. This has many problems, such as only one spinner being allowed at once.

```
global_switch = 'off'

def loader(label, switch):
    global lbl1, lbl2, global_switch

    if not switch==None:
        global_switch = switch

    if global_switch == 'off':
        ....
    if global_switch == 'on':
        ....
            loader(label, None)
main.mainloop()
```

However, I would recommend a much neater approach using classes. (There are some untested commented-out suggestions on converting it to using the images instead of text). Also, you can't safely make tkinter calls outside the main thread, so although this wasn't the original problem you asked about, I've used the `root`'s `after` method in place of threads and `time.sleep()`s.

Here is the solution I would recommend:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import threading
main = Tk()


def threadspawner():
    global var1
    global var2
    print(var1.get(),var2.get())
    if var1.get() != 0:
        lbl1.start() #<-- starts the spinning wheel to show that something is happening
        time.sleep(1)  #start doing stuff here
        lbl1.stop() #<-- Turns off the spinning wheel
    if var2.get() != 0:
        lbl2.start() #<-- starts the spinning wheel to show that something is happening
        time.sleep(2)
        lbl2.stop() #<-- Turns off the spinning wheel

class Loader(Label):
    positions_text = '/-\\'
    #positions_imgs = [PhotoImage(file='icons\\wheel.gif', format="gif -index "+str(i)) for i in range(3)]
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['text']=''
        Label.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.runnng = False
        self.pos = 0
    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.parent.after(0,self.update)

    def update(self):
        self.config(text = self.positions_text[self.pos])
        #self.config(image = self.positions_imgs[self.pos])
        self.pos = (self.pos+1)%len(self.positions_text)
        #self.pos = (self.pos+1)%len(self.positions_imgs)
        if self.running:
            self.parent.after(100,self.update)
        else:
            self.config(text = '✓')
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False



var1 = IntVar()
chk1 = Checkbutton(main, text='process1', onvalue=2, offvalue=0, variable=var1)
chk1.grid(row=1)
lbl1 = Loader(main) # create an instance of the Loader class
lbl1.grid(row=1, column=1)

var2 = IntVar()
chk2 = Checkbutton(main, text='process2', variable=var2)
chk2.grid(row=2)
lbl2 = Loader(main) # create an instance of the Loader class
lbl2.grid(row=2, column=1)

strt = Button(main, text='Start', command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=threadspawner).start())
strt.grid(columnspan=2)

main.mainloop()
```

NB: I have also made some other minor changes in the code.